# Is it possible to change TeamCity's artifacts path

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-5.0

The default path for teamcity artifacts is

> C:\#User#\.BuildServer\system\artifacts

How can i change it to

> d:\TeamCity\Artifacts

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For me the default is D:\BuildServer\system\artifacts

Yes you can, set the TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH environment variable.

See here: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/TeamCity+Data+Directory

> By default, the  is placed in the user's
>   home directory (e.g. it is
>   $HOME/.BuildServer under Linux and
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\.BuildServer)
>   under Windows. Alternatively, you can
>   define this directory in one of the
>   following ways:
>
> 1. As a Tomcat system property teamcity.data.path (see System
>      Properties for Running the Server)
> 2. In the TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH environment variable (this will be
>      used if the teamcity.data.path JVM
>      system property is not found)

Comment: Thanks this led me onto the right track.  To be specific run "c:\TeamCity\bin\tomcat6w.exe //ES//TeamCity" then change the "-Dteamcity.data.path" under the Java tab

Comment: That's for setting the value from the command line, you can also set your environment variables from the System Properties panel (System in the Control Panel, select Advanced in Windows 7 - not sure about windows XP + Vista) go to the Advanced Tab and see the button at the bottom Environment Variables. In here you can set a new variable called TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH..

Comment: As it also says in the docs: If you run TeamCity as Windows service installed via standard procedure from the Windows executable file, you will need to modify the teamcity.data.path Tomcat JVM property via @Anton P's instructions. Modifying the TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH environment variable will not work in this case.

Comment: For those hunting, i set this in my runall.sh    export TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH="/media/storage/teamcity/"

Comment: @Ezz But `TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH` used with whole server inculding configs etc. How can be changed anly "artifacts storage"?

Comment: Same question as setevoy - what if you only want to relocate the artifacts? In my case the artifacts are huge and I want to move them to a SAN, but keep the config etc local.