# TeamCity: collecting artifact to custom directory?

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

Have task - deploy `application.war` in to Tomcat's directory after build.

`application.war` collected from `buildAgent` box to server box. But - it always have different absolute path - because uses `buildId` in pathname:

```
 /home/teamcity/.BuildServer/system/artifacts/ProjectName/buildName/BUILD_ID/application.war
```

Using any path for target directories like `...\application.war => /home/teamcity/directory` - does'n put file in to `/home/teamcity/directory` in TeamCity home - it always uses `/home/teamcity/.BuildServer/system/artifacts/buildName/BUILD_ID/home/teamcity/directory` as `"HOME"`.

So - I can't us `deploy.script` - because it don't know current `BUILD_ID`.

What is correct way to solve it?

**UPD** changing variable `TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH` affect whole server inculding configs etc. How can be changed only "artifacts storage"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change TeamCity's artifacts path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092604/is-it-possible-to-change-teamcitys-artifacts-path)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're building with `maven` or `gradle` and my proffered way would be to use build script to deploy artefact correctly.

However to answer your question. Have you looked to artefacts paths of TeamCity:

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_ID/.lastFinished/ARTIFACT_PATH
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_ID/.lastSuccessful/ARTIFACT_PATH
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_ID/.lastPinned/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

You can find more documentation here - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts